# PostgreSQL CREATE TABLE AS Function

Tags: sql, postgresql

using postgres db, and i am creating a table using

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_yyymmdd 
    AS TABLE parent_tabble 
    WITH NO DATA;
```

i am successfully creating the table column and type are correct, but the nullable on table_yyymmdd is emppty, can i use create table as to duplicate also nullable part?

my parent table:

```
        Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default         
----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------
 id                   | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 id_transaction       | text                        |           | not null | 
 id_account           | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 id_number            | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 transaction_time     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
 amount               | integer                     |           | not null | 
 fee                  | integer                     |           | not null | 
 validity             | integer                     |           | not null | 
 notification_message | text                        |           |          |
```

my create child table:

```
        Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id                   | bigint                      |           |          | 
 id_transaction       | text                        |           |          | 
 id_account           | bigint                      |           |          | 
 id_number            | bigint                      |           |          | 
 transaction_time     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 amount               | integer                     |           |          | 
 fee                  | integer                     |           |          | 
 validity             | integer                     |           |          | 
 notification_message | text                        |           |          |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE TABLE AS creates a new table based on a (SELECT) query. `TABLE parent_table` is just a short version of `select * from parent_table`. So the new table can only be created based on the result from the SELECT.

If you want to create a copy of a table without data, but including constraints, use the `create table ... LIKE` syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_yyymmdd 
(
  LIKE parent_table 
     INCLUDING constraints
     INCLUDING defaults
);
```

More details [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6)